# Does this prove that two lines are parallel?

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

I was recently given this problem:
Suppose we have a triangle $ABC$ and let there be a cevian $AD$. Let the foot of the perpendicular from $B$ to $AD$ be $P$ and let the intersection of the extension of $BP$ to $AC$ be $Q$. Prove that $DQ$ and $AB$ are parallel.

So I extended a line from $D$ parallel to $AC$ and let it intersect $AB$ at $R$. By rules of parallel lines, this means that $\widehat{BAD}=\widehat{BDQ}$ which also means that $AB$ and $DQ$ are parallel. However, this seems too simple. Does this approach work?

Comment: "this means that"... what?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement does not seem to be true. Here is a diagram fitting your requirements, and we clearly see that $\overline{DQ}$ is not parallel to $\overline{AB}$. We also see that your approach with point $R$ does not seem to work.

[image]

Did you intend a *particular* cevian with point $D$, or just any $D$ on $\overline{BC}$?